# Tab bar when move to other view controller

Tags: ios, uistoryboard

I have a problem with the tab bar for my app.  When I open my app the bottom tab appears since I am using the Tab bar controller however when I move to another view controller and come back the tab bar is gone. Do I have to do something to the storyboard?

Comment: How are moving to this other controller, and how are you coming back?

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: I am using a storyboard. I have a tab bar controller and a have 3 view controllers connected to it each have tabs down so that it is easy to switch. One tab has a button and when push that button it goes to another view controller. and when I come back to the tabbed view controller the tab is gone.I am not using code.

Comment: That doesn't explain *how* you're going to and from this view controller. What is that button connected to, a segue? How about when you come back, is that done with a segue? If so, how is that segue connected??

Comment: Ok I am using a storyboard.  I have a TAB BAR CONTROLLER.  The tab bar controller is connected with two view controllers that have bottom tabs using a storyboard segue(Relationship). I have a button on one of those view controllers lets say forestviewcon.  I have connected that button to another view controller lets say appleviewcon using a segue. on the appleviewcon I have a back button that connects to back to the forestviewcon.  When I push the back button it displays forestviewcon but without the tab button.no code used

Comment: So is forestviewcon embedded in a navigation controller? Is the back button you're talking about in  appleviewcon , the one you get automatically when using a navigation controller, or is it one you added yourself? BTW, when you respond to someone's comment, you should  include "@username" in your comment so that person will be notified that you've responded.

Comment: @rdelmar forestviewcon is embedded in a tab bar controller. This is my storyboard now http://i58.tinypic.com/15zqusi.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, as I suspected, you're going "back" in an incorrect way. You should never go backwards to a previous controller with a segue unless you use an unwind segue. What you're doing is instantiating a new instance of that controller you think you're going back to -- one that isn't embedded in a tab bar controller. So, you either need to use an unwind segue, or go back in code using dismissViewController:animated:completion: (assuming that you're using modal segues to go forward).

Comment: Thank you I have heard of an unwind segue and I tried it previously i used the code `- (IBAction)firstViewReturnActionForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue
{
    NSLog(@"First view return action invoked.");
}` I added this on my forestviewcon. I pushed the exit and connected this segue with the back button.  I think I am doing the right thing

Comment: No its not letting me go back. Even though I tap the button nothing occurs

Comment: @user3511110, I'm not sure what's wrong then. That should work. If you right click on your button, does it show that connection in the window that comes up (there should be a "Triggered Segues" section in the window that has "action" on the left side, and "unwind" on the right with "firstViewReturnActionForSegue" underneath)?

Comment: Ok it worked. When I made another class it worked. Strange. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you navigate to another view with the following:

```
NamedViewController *svc = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"NamedViewController"];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:svc animated:YES];
```

and use the following to go back it should work.

```
[[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES] viewWillAppear:YES];
```